# How to consume API with search in Laravel 7 Blade?

Tags: laravel, api, search, laravel-blade

[image: API result]

I have an API that can get by searching keyword(s).

I want to consume it with Laravel Blade. So, I made a ViewHadController:

```
    public function cari(Request $request)
    {
        $cari = $request->cari;
        $response = Http::get('http://hadits.test/api/hadall/cari?isi=$cari');
        $data = $response->json();
        //dd($data);
        return view('hadits', compact('data'));
    }
```

If I replace $cari with any keywords, return is okay.

Already tried build this in view.blade.php:

```
    <div class="container">
            <form action="/cari" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="cari" placeholder="Cari Hadits .." value="{{ old('cari') }}">
            <input type="submit" value="CARI">
            </form>
    </div>
```

with this web.routes:
`Route::get('/{cari}', 'ViewHadController@cari');`

When the keyword hard-coded, the results are okay:

[image: Hardcoded]

But no luck if using search parameter, always return blank. Is there any tutorials how to consume that API with search form in Laravel Blade?

[image: Search Result]

Comment: Try changing `'hadits.test/api/hadall/cari?isi=$cari'` to `"http://hadits.test/api/hadall/cari?isi=$cari"` note the protocol and the use of double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: Thank you, but in my original code: ```'http://hadits.test/api/hadall/cari?isi=$cari'``` and if i hardcode the keyword, result is shown up.

Comment: Those are still single quotes

Comment: OMG, I thought I already use double quotes. Thank you, my problem is solved.